# How to deal with large projects in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io, coding-style

Now that I know some of the basics of C++, I must admit that I still find it very hard to deal with code that others have written in C++. This may inherently be so, as C++ allows for complex object hierarchies that are, or at least to me, very hard to grasp if one is just supplied with a C++ Project without any further comments or instructions.

So my question is more a question to the more experienced C++ programmers among you: **how can someone understand a large C++ project written by others?**

I easily loose my way and can be lost for weeks, if I try to understand how a large project of, for example, 10,000 lines of code is written. Functions of classes are pointers to functions of different classes that may or may not be overloaded and may or may not be inherited by other classes, etcetera, without ending.

Are there any practical tips that may speed up my ability to read and understand large C++ projects? Is there perhaps a tutorial with such tips? Please, elaborate! :)

Comment: ...I don't think we are going to be able to explain "Software Engineering", and entire discipline, in a stack overflow answer. But yeah. Take courses. Write code. Get experience. Read a lot of code. Read more code. Maintain code bases. Document your code. Document others code. Fix bugs in open source code bases. Get your degree. Attend conferences. Ect.

Comment: You may find it useful to reverse engineer the code into UML diagrams, using a tool such as [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) (be aware that very few of these tools are able to reverse engineer C++ - StarUML is one of them). This gives you a nice overview of the code.

Comment: Before looking at others project, try to make your own small project...and when you feel you are done then try to read others project and learn good practices.

Comment: @Learning You cannot learn how to read code by writing code.

Comment: @IInspectable without writing small codes how can someone learn coding by reding someones large project... If you can then you are someone extra ordinary.

Comment: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/how-do-you-dive-into-large-code-bases

Comment: You don't need to understand all the code in order to maintain it.  Get doxygen and graphviz.  Run the project through doxygen and have a look at the diagrams generated.  That tells you the class structure.  See how many hoops you need to jump through to say add a new dialog, add a new object type, change a title.  Try fixing a simple bug: that is normally a good start.  Tutorials: have a look at the source of wordpad in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y8h3tk(v=vs.90).aspx and try adding overscores or changing the colour of the background.

Comment: And a good text search tool (like Agent Ransack) is great to help track references in the code base.

Comment: Some have flagged this question as too broad. I understand these concerns, but I would prefer to see this forum to remain open for non-technical, open questions such as this one, as they may of great help to (beginning) programmers just as well as more specific, technical questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been programming professionally for some time now, and as such I have repeatedly been handed down codebases written by others before me. Understanding is never easy, especially when the code is inconsistent.

The first thing to realize, though, is that learning your ways in a new codebase is not so different than re-discovering a codebase you had not touched for a while. Thus, whether written by your old-self of others does not matter much; and since you probably manage to cope with re-discovering codebases you had worked on before, you should be able to discover new codebases as well. Don't lose hope.

The second thing to realize is that *understanding* is a vague term, and there are certainly different degrees. Often times, nobody asks you to understand the ins and outs completely; more likely you will be asked to understand *a portion* of the codebase in which either there is a bug or some new functionality should be developed. Therefore, as time passes, you will gradually gain an understanding of various portions, and you will inevitably have a deeper knowledge of the portions you worked the most whilst others can be relatively abstract or even completely obscure. It's okay, it's been a long time since human beings stopped trying to learn everything there was to learn.

With that said, there are several axis of understanding you can try:

- you should look for *architecture*: a good thing is to trace the library dependencies (the Makefile/Project should help here) this will give you the coarse technical blocks out of which the application is built. Executables are normally leaves of the dependency trees.
- you should look for *data-flow*: what's the trigger of the application (called directly or as a callback) ? what are the steps followed by this data (roughly, just a sketch). Do not hesitate to focus on a specific *narrow* usecase and use the debugger to trace things, and do not try to dig too deep at first; just get a feel of things.

There are also other axis that may help gaining some understanding of the *domain* the application has been written for. An understanding of the domain is useful because it provides you with a key insight on what *should* happen and it also helps you decipher the comments/function names.

- user documentation: what is this used for ? if you can arrange for a demo it is generally very helpful, otherwise maybe you can try playing with it yourself (in a test environment)
- tests: what is tested ? what is exposed to the user ?
- persistent data: what is serialized ? what is saved in a database ? Persistent data is accessed at some point, so it helps if you understand when it is read/written.

Comment: I have one question: how can the Makefile/Project help me with nailing down the architecture of a project?

Comment: *If* your project is split into several libraries (and large projects are) then it helps you understand which libraries depend on each other. This helps you locate *roots*: libraries that do not depend on any other libraries and can be understood *in isolation*; as well as *leaves*: libraries that no other library depend on and therefore are *entry-points* (or else would be useless). From then, you can either start from roots or entry-points to discover the application (or start from both and hope you join both halves).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a working product (that runs) and you can "debug" it, start by looking at just one particular feature.

Learn how it is working from the user's point of view (UI, behaviour, inputs, outputs, ...).

Once you know the feature from the outside, just look for the code for that feature (only that feature); the starting point might be a handler for a menu, or from a dialog or a mouse/pointer event.

From there; manually trace the code for one action or sub-feature; skip deep internal libraries (treat them as black box for now) and learn how it works.

Once you know that section of code, dig deeper in libraries API that was called from the upper level code.

Take your time.
Do not try to understand everything at once.
Draw up schematic (pen and paper) of the dependencies (stay high level, no class dependencies at the beginning).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, these pieces of wisdom are of help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are mentioning does not have clear and simple answer. Nevertheless here are some tips:

1. At the beginning try to randomly remember everything. Names of directories, classes, params of templates, etc. As much as you can. This sounds pointless but still makes sense.
2. While working with the code always think "Have I looked at this function/param/etc before?" If the answer is yes, spend with this piece of code more. If not, just make basic grasp and go on.
3. As the time will go on, you will find out that more and more sounds clear and easier to grasp.
4. It is impossible to give any exact values because size and complexity of projects vary greatly. Do not expect simple and immediate results.

Other points:

1. You definitely need a source code browser. Spend time in learning how to use it. Good example is http://sourceinsight.com/. This is not my site!!! I do have my own site. I will not mention it here.
2. If you see a function that is called 500 times, it is 500 times more likely that knowledge about this function will be useful comparing with a function, that is called only once.

The best is to grasp the architecture of the project. Trying to do this it is necessary to remember that project may have no architecture at all.

Studying the code you should remember your task. Typical situation - you need to modify something or fix a bug. If this is so look for the right part of the code and focus your effort on it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the source code browser site. With respect to the first point you mention: remember as much as possible -- I try to but when so many functions and variables are called in so many different places with only slightly different names, this can be really hard, even for someone whose me memory is generally not bad...